# Flexbox: A way to align individual element along main axis

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was wondering if there is a way to override alignment along main axis for individual element. Something like this:

[image: flexbox challenge]

In the picture above, all the elements have `align-items: flex-start`, except of the last one, which needs to be aligned as `flex-end`, or `space-around`.

There is an option to override along cross axis: `align-self`, but probably not along main axis.

What is bad with doing this with `position: absolute`: the other elements should respect that special one, and not overlap with it.

What is bad with `float` is that it works for `flex-direction: row` only.

Comment: If flexbox is a way to distribute items on rows and colums, how could you tell flexbox to leave that space? It is just not what flexbox is for.
Maybe you could do this with multiple flexboxes one inside the other.

Comment: maybe you can utilize position:relative for the element. you might also provide a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element set to `flex-grow: 1` and order it so it fills the space you want between the elements.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  counter-reset: counter;
}
.flex:before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  order: 1;
}
.flex div {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 1%;
}
.flex div:before {
  counter-increment: counter;
  content: counter(counter);
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.flex div:last-child {
  order: 2;
  flex-basis: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 35):

Simply set margin-left to "auto" for the 4th element. When aligning items along the main axis, auto margins are the way to go.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, `margin-top: auto` or `margin-bottom: auto` work too!

Comment: This should have been the selected answer, imo

Comment: Why didn't OP select this answer? This one is so simple.

Comment: Conditional exists for this statement: it is true only if the main axis is horizontal. It does not work for me in the flex container with `flex-direction: column-reverse;`, just like `margin: auto;` does not work for centering an element vertically.